# how to move files in directories in group of 3

Tags: python, shutil

I have 60 files and 20 folders in same directory.
I want to move first three files to the first folder, next three files to another folder and so on.

Basically move 60 files in group of three into 20 folders.

I made a list including path for each file, but for the part that move them to folders I'm not sure what to do:

```py
import os
import shutil

path = r'C:\.......\est Files'
destination = r'C:\.......\est Files

paths = []

for root, dirs, file in os.walk(path):
    for name in file:
        paths.append(os.path.join(root,name))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil

# Get the list of files in the current directory
files = os.listdir()

# Filter the list of files to only include regular files
files = [f for f in files if os.path.isfile(f)]

# Create a list of folders to move the files to
folders = [f"folder{i+1}" for i in range(20)]

# Loop over each group of three files
for i in range(0, len(files), 3):
    # Create a path for each file in the group
    file_paths = [os.path.join(os.getcwd(), files[j]) for j in range(i, i+3)]

    # Move the group of files to the next folder
    for path in file_paths:
        shutil.move(path, folders[i // 3])
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. i ran the code, it runs with no error but it will just delete the first 3 images and nothing else.